# jQuery scroll to top shows the button without scrolling the page

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

Hello my code looks okay but I don't know why its visible without scrolling the page.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    //Check to see if the window is top if not then display button
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('.TopButton').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('.TopButton').fadeOut();
        }
    });
    //Click event to scroll to top
    $('.TopButton').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},360);
        return false;
    });
});
```

So, I have used `if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100` but when I open the page its showing the button without scrolling the page.When I scroll the page and go back to top its working and hiding the button.

Do you have any idea what Im doing wrong?

Comment: In your css add **display:none** for .TopButton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    // hide the topbutton on page load/ready.
    $('.TopButton').hide();

    //Check to see if the window is top if not then display button
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('.TopButton').show().fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('.TopButton').fadeOut().hide();
        }
    });
    //Click event to scroll to top
    $('.TopButton').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},360);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The scroll event occurs when the user scrolls in the specified element.

So, check for the position of the scrollbar on document load.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    //check if window scroll is < 100
    if($(window).scrollTop() < 100){
         $('.TopButton').fadeOut().hide();
    }
    //Check to see if the window is top if not then display button
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('.TopButton').show().fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('.TopButton').fadeOut().hide();
        }
    });
    //Click event to scroll to top
    $('.TopButton').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},360);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Or you may even hide the button by default, as Mr.ZZ mentioned in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the scrollTop on ready, now you are doing it only on scroll.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  //Check to see if the window is top if not then display button
  toggleButton()
  $(window).scroll(toggleButton);
  //Click event to scroll to top
  $('.TopButton').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},360);
    return false;
  });
});

function toggleButton() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
    $('.TopButton').fadeIn();
  } else {
    $('.TopButton').fadeOut();
  }
}
```

Comment: hey @gg_ thanks for your reply replaced it with your code and cleared the browser cache since Im working localy but its still showing it, I know its very strange.

Comment: Replace `$` with `jQuery`